# Why is the solution to $y' = y^n$ always in polynomial form EXCEPT when $n = 1$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, exponential-function

Could someone explain (intuition-wise) why the differential equation

$$y' = y^n$$

for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ seems to always some kind of polynomial solution (or a ratio of polynomials, etc.) **except** when $n = 1$, in which case the solution seems to be exponential?

What's so special about $n = 1$ that (if you'll pardon the term) differentiates it from e.g. $n = 2$?

Comment: The equation is linear only when $n=1$.

Comment: When n=1 the equation states that the function is its own derivative, the exponential is unique in that respect

Comment: @John: And it's quadratic only when $n = 2$, and cubic only when $n = 3$...

Comment: @Dan: I could very well have written $y' = 2 y^n$ and that would no longer have been the case. You could argue that any function satisfying the differential equation is unique in that respect, but that doesn't say much.

Comment: Linearity is not just another condition on differential equation. Linear differential equations has different properties as nonlinear one.

Comment: True but that only points to the class of solutions $e^{kx}$, in fact the exponential function has a definition which includes this equation at its core, so this is one of the defining equations that brought us such a nice function. This further lead to using it in linear differential equations in general when wanting to substitute solutions.

Answer (score 5):

If you rewrite equation: $$\frac{dy}{y^n}=dx,$$
and then
$$\int_{y_0}^y \frac{dy}{y^n}=x-x_0,$$
you should take integral. But case $n=1$ is special — integral is $\ln y$, not a $\frac{y^{1-n}}{1-n}$.

Comment: +1 though I meant this question to be asked on a slightly deeper level than that, but this is nice to point out anyway...

Comment: thanks, but what do you mean on "slightly deeper level"?

Comment: I mean, just blindly looking at the equation, I would expect the solution to $y' = y^2$ to look something like $e^{x^2}$, because the equation is literally saying that its derivative is much larger than its current value. I wouldn't expect it to look like a polynomial, especially because the polynomial contains a pole at a finite value whereas an exponential doesn't (and I don't see why changing $n$ should suddenly introduce a pole in the solution).